# Rails 4 + SimpleForm - different wrapper for one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use SimpleForm with Rails 4.

I defined my own wrapper for `:form_horizontal`, which puts the label in `col-sm-3` and the input in `col-sm-9` on the right of it. It leaves the form in this format:

```
    first name    [____________________________] 

     last name    [____________________________] 

         color    [____________________________]
```

I need to define a different wrapper for a specific case inside this general form, where two fields should appear in same line with a customize label:

```
    first name    [____________________________] 

     last name    [____________________________] 

         color    [____________________________] 

     something    [____________]  [____________]
```

I could not find in the documentation how can it be done. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Just add on the inputfield an attribute:

```
wrapper: :name_of_your_wrapper
```